# Extjs: How to use store record as a store for grid

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs3

**Overview of what I need to accomplish:**
I've been working with Ext for a few months.  I've been using js since forever.  Doing this in any other framework or with just jquery would be a simple matter. In angular, I'd just use ng-grid to display the data for the selected day.  Trying to figure it out in Ext is making my head hurt.

I have some JSON data that looks a lot like this...

```
{
    "Id":"1",
    "Sunday":[
        {"Start":"10:15","End":"17:45"}, 
        {"Start":"20:00","End":"23:00"}, 
        {"Start":"00:15","End":"06:15"}, 
        {"Start":"08:00","End":"10:00"}
    ],
    "Monday":[],
    "Tuesday":[],
    "Wednesday":[],
    "Thursday":[],
    "Friday":[],
    "Saturday":[]
}
```

***What I actually need to do:***
I have two controls on an ExtJs 3.4.0 page/panel/whatever:

1. an Ext Combo Box (dropdown list) containing days of week (possibly from the store)
2. an Ext grid to display the array of things for that day

Behavior:
When an entry from the dropdown is chosen, the associated data for that day of the week is used to populate rows in the grid.  The column model is trivial, i'm not worried about anything other than how the data actually gets from the JSON store and into the grid after a day is selected.

to re-iterate: what I'm having trouble getting my head around is how to use a store record as a store to populate the grid.

Ideally, I'd populate an arrayStore with the JSON data and just use a line like:

```
new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
...
    store: new Ext.data.Store(data: arrayOfSchedules[drodown.getValue()])
...
})
```

I can provide a plunker or something similar if that's what it takes.  The format of the data really defines everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create new grid/store on each combo select. You can extract data from the selected day (Sunday) and then you can use [grid.store.loadData](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadData) to update the grid.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!  The thing I've struggled with the most is actually getting my head around the ext documentation.  There are very few examples referenced there, so it is hard to know exactly what anything really does or how it should be implemented.